# If the i-th, j-th, and k-th terms in an AP are in a GP with ratio r, find $r$ in terms of $i, j$, and $k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

If the i-th, j-th, and k-th terms 
in an arithmetic progression 
are in a geometric progression 
with ratio r,
find r in terms 
of i, j, and k.

This is my result:

(1) if $ik \ne j^2$
then $r=\frac{k-j}{j-i}$;
(2) if $ik = j^2$
then $r=\frac{j}{i}$.

I solved this
here
([Arithmetic and Geometric Progression Question 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1350424/arithmetic-and-geometric-progression-question-1/1350532#1350532))
but I feel my proof is awkward,
and my hope is that
someone can come up with a more
elegant solution.

Comment: As a small point, in the second case, $j/i = k/j$, so you can rewrite the answer to look like the ratio of case 1...but without the subtracted bits. This didn't lead me to any further insight, however. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get the bifurcation by cases, so maybe I have an error.  Here is my calculation anyway, for what it is worth:

For simplicity, let A be the $j^{th}$ term and P the arithmetic period.  Then the $i^{th}$ term is A + (i-j)P and the $k^{th}$ term is A + (k-j)P.  The assumtion then implies that $$ \frac{A}{A+(i-j)P} = \frac{A+(k-j)P}{A}$$

Either of these quotients give the geometric ratio you seek.  Cross multiply and simplify to get $$ 0 = (k + i - 2j)A  + (i-j)P \Rightarrow P = \frac{2j-k-i}{(i-j)(k-j)}A$$

To get the desired ratio substitute this expression for P into one of the (equivalent) quotients which gives the ratio.  Using the right hand quotient we quickly get that the desired ratio is $$1 + \frac{2j - k-i}{i-j} = \frac{j-k}{i-k}=\frac{k-j}{j-i}$$
Not sure where the bifurcation might arise....

Comment: I think the bifurcation might apply if A=0.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that your answer's second case is redundant. If $j^2=ik$ then $$\frac{k}{j}=\frac{j}{i} = \frac{k-j}{j-i}$$ when $j\neq i$. (Note that if $i=0$ or $j=0$ then one of the others must be zero, so $i,j,k$ are not distinct in that case.)

Now, if $a,b,c$ are distinct and in geometric progression, then they must be non-zero, so $$r=\frac{b}{a}=\frac{c}{b}=\frac{c-b}{b-a}$$

If they are in arithmetic progression also, with indices $i,j,k$, then:

$$\frac{c-b}{b-a}=\frac{k-j}{j-i}$$

So the heart of this is the basic result:

$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d},c\neq d\implies\frac{a-c}{b-d}=\frac{a}{b}.$$

Comment: Nice! But it doesn't handle the case where $b = 0$, or where $j$ is the average of $i$ and $k$ (in which case I think $b = 0$ is also true).

Comment: If $b=0$ then the progression is a constant sequence and $r=1$.

Comment: If $b=0$ then $r=1$, and $i,j,k$ can be any values, which makes the case uninteresting. @JohnHughes

Comment: You chose to divide by i+k-2j, so you need to consider what happens when this is zero.

Comment: @martycohen true. If that is zero, then $j^2-ik\neq 0$ or $i=j=k$ by AM/GM. So then $b=0$, which we've excluded.

Comment: As I showed in the answer I linked to, you can't have both i+k=2j and $ik=j^2$.

Comment: Which I just showed in one line.it follows from AM/GM. @martycohen you can have it, but only when $i=j=k$

Comment: I *knew* that, but I thought that you might want to mention it for clarity (which you now have).

Comment: @martycohen I've come up with a much easier answer that exposes the nature of the simple formula.